# WSO2 REST add.jag gets null pointer exception

Tags: java, api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to add an API using REST add.jag. Tried it on both 1.9.1 and 1.10.0. In the dashboard UI it is added ok, but with the following message

```
Status code: 200
{
    "message": " null",
    "error": true
}
```

And log file shows

```
[2016-01-10 16:21:22,956] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-add.ajax.add:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-add.ajax.add:jag}
```

I'm running this in both CURL and Python, get the same error.
Here is the body I send to the REST:

```
body = {
  "action" : "addAPI",
  "name" : "employee",
  "context" : "/employee",
  "version=" : "1.0.0",
  "visibility" : "public",
  "description" : "list employees",
  "endpointType" : "nonsecured",

  "http_checked" : "http",
  "https_checked" : "https",

  "tier" : "Unlimited",
  "tiersCollection" : "Unlimited,Silver",

  "environments" : "Production",
  "resourceCount" : "0",
  "resourceMethod-0" : "GET",
  "resourceMethodAuthType-0" : "Application",
  "resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0" : "Unlimited",

  "endpointConfig" : '{"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://localhost:8080/sample2/api/company/employees","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
  "endpointType" : "nonsecured" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it to work.
Below is the updated set of body parameters
Seems that the missing one was uriTemplate-0.

```
body
{
  "action" : "addAPI",
  "name" : "employee",
  "context" : "/employee",
  "version" : "1.0.0",
  "visibility" : "public",
  "thumburl" : "",
  "description" : "list employees",
  "tags" : "company,employees",
  "endpointType" : "nonsecured",
  "tiersCollection" : "Gold,Silver",

  "http_checked" : "http",
  "https_checked" : "https",

  "bizOwner" : "xx",
  "bizOwnerMail" : "xx@ee.com",
  "techOwner" : "xx",
  "techOwnerMail" : "xx@ee.com",

  'resourceCount': '0',
  'resourceMethod-0': 'GET',
  "resourceMethodAuthType-0" : "Application",
  'resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0': 'Unlimited',
  "uriTemplate-0" : "/*",

  'default_version_checked': 'default_version',

  'endpoint_config': '{"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
}
```